# select/deselect methods in Python

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm reading *Programming Python* by Mark Lutz, and I came across this bit of code that I don't get.

```
buttons = []

def onpress(i):
    global state
    state = i
    for btn in buttons:
        btn.deselect()
    buttons[i].select()
```

I get what it's doing, but I don't get where these select and deselect methods are coming from.  I've never seen these list methods before (I and the book are using Python 3).  Are these builtin methods?  And what do they do?  I tried using my Google-fu to figure it out, but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Python/0360__Tkinker/Deselectforradiobuttonssimplysetsthebuttonsassociatedvaluetoanullstring.htm

So a quick google, if you are doing this it means you are most likely using tkinter in which case you have missing relevant code somewhere.

Those methods .deselect() and .select() are actually tkinter Radiobuttons() methods. If you're tutorial reverences tkinter. "from tkinter import *" will import those class's. If not i have no idea why its being taken out of context.

But what this code does is, it takes 'i', which is a button you click, then it sets 'state' to 'i', making 'state' 'global' over writing the last 'state', then it deselects all buttons, and selects 'i' which is your new choice. In effect this means you'll only ever select 1 button

If you wonder why state is an empty string, its because an empty string is the first button in tkinter. When you pass a new string in, it gives the new item being something like "I001" or something.

Comment: I feel mildly embarrassed.  The fact that the methods reference objects within the list rather than the list itself was right in front of me.  I realized it a quarter of the way through reading your post.